# Plotting a boxplot against multiple factors and overlay raw data in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a boxplot like this;

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(am)))
```

so this plots the data as boxplots that underlie two factors, one with two levels, the other one with three levels.

Now I would like to overlay the raw data.
But if I add geom_points;

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(am))) +
geom_point()
```

It ignores one of the factors and plots the collapsed raw data in the middle of the grouped boxplots.

Is there an easy workaround, so that the geom_points are actually plotted correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: ok, thanks! I found this on CrossValidated: [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146148/plotting-a-boxplot-against-multiple-factors-and-overlay-raw-data-in-r-with-ggplo) and thought it would be a natural follow up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the points like it is default for `geom_boxplot`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = .7))
```

Comment: great, thank you! Can you also combine position_dodge with position_jitter?

Comment: I guess you'd have to work around - see e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=ggplot+combine+position_dodge+and+position_jitter

Comment: Ah, didn't know of `position_jitterdodge()`. Cool. :-)